# Bash script - if and else if statements

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I am quite new to bash scripts so take it easy on me;).

I have a file which does some checks before initiating a /warner file which sends an email.

No what the script should do is:

If the word 'rror' is to be found in the log file and if the file is younger then 24 hours > send failed email

If the file is older than 24 hours > send not running error

If none of the above are true and the file is less than 24 hours old and if it contains word 'uccess' > send successful email.

Script it self

```
string=rror
string1=ucces

FILE=/var/log/rsnapshot.log
OLDTIME=86400
CURTIME=$(date +%s)
FILETIME=$(stat $FILE -c %Y)
TIMEDIFF=$(expr $CURTIME - $FILETIME)

#tail -n0 -F /var/log/rsnapshot.log | \

while read LINE
do
  if [ echo "$LINE" | grep "$string" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 -a $TIMEDIFF -lt $OLDTIME ]; // <- line 18
    then
        /etc/init.d/warner "Warning from Socrates Backup" "Backup Failed"
  elif [ $TIMEDIFF -gt $OLDTIME ];
    then
        /etc/init.d/warner "Warning from Socrates Backup - Backup Not Running!" "Backup file not running"
  elif echo "$LINE" | grep "$string1" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    then
        /etc/init.d/warner "Message from Socrates" "Backup Sucessfully Completed"
  fi
done </var/log/rsnapshot.log
```

At present time it does send me a successfull email (because the file is less than 24hours and it does have a 'uccess' message. However are these if / elseif written correctly ? if anything should fail will they get triggered ? and also i am getting this error

```
line 18: [: missing `]'
```

Comment: Where is line 18? If I count the lines you pasted, it is in `then`.

Comment: @fedorqui Apologies did not see your comment. The 18th line is the first if

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is completely wrong:

```
if [ echo "$LINE" | grep "$string" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 -a $TIMEDIFF -lt $OLDTIME ];
```

What you mean probably is:

```
if echo "$LINE" | grep -q "$string" && [ $TIMEDIFF -lt $OLDTIME ];
```

You want to read `Compound Commands` from the `man bash`, while keeping in mind that `[` is just a command too. (Try `help test`.)

Comment: Yup thats the one. i have to do more RTFM

Comment: @MaciejCygan, In the beginning, the internal bash's `help` command was extremely useful to me. The `man bash` is just too huge to swallow, while for basic syntax the `help <cmd>` + googling is more than sufficient.